# Problemas con Heroku-Ruby

Tags: ruby, heroku

ayer al tratar de pushear mi proyecto a heroku y al ingresar al dominio, me doy cuenta que mi aplicacion no estaba funcionando, todo funcionaba perfectamente hasta que pushie una branch que tenia private_pub gema que utiliza faye para chat en tiempo real, despues me meti a hacerlo con actioncable y borre los archivos generados por private_pub, la aplicacion hace correctamente el bundle install y esta el db:migrate tambien hecho, lo que mas me asombra es que en local me fuinciona todo perfectamente y no recibo ningun problema, en la ultima branch que pushie tengo redis, tambien configurado para produccion config/environments/production.rb como asi tambien en config/cable.yml usando el adaptador de redis de Redis Lab dejo el log de heroku desde ya muchas gracias!

```
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210147+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210159+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.0.beta1 application starting in production on http://localhost:28307
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210160+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210161+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210166+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210167+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210169+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-02-25T19:54:55.210311+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://localhost:28307
2017-02-25T19:54:55.211136+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-25T19:55:51.654696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-02-25T19:55:51.654835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-02-25T19:55:51.761922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-25T19:55:51.763287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-02-25T19:55:51.766138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-02-25T19:55:56.264770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29901 -e production`
2017-02-25T19:56:01.901976+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902007+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.0.beta1 application starting in production on http://localhost:29901
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902014+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902015+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902020+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902028+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902029+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902108+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://localhost:29901
2017-02-25T19:56:01.902707+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-25T19:56:04.448511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=carmeloapp.herokuapp.com request_id=f6fe0ac3-8307-4d42-9875-c133e0f2daa8 fwd="152.170.14.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-25T19:56:56.679884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-02-25T19:56:56.679939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-02-25T19:56:56.785791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-02-25T19:56:56.796102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-25T20:05:48.214407+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-02-25T20:05:53.559843+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2017-02-25T20:05:54.258262+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-25T20:05:59.687811+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-02-25T20:05:59.740228+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-02-25T20:05:59.553953+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2017-02-25T20:05:59.553982+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work' (see --tasks)
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554201+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554202+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554203+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554204+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554205+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554211+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554221+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554222+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554222+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554223+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554223+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554224+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in '
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554224+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554225+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554226+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554227+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `'
2017-02-25T20:05:59.554292+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Cual es tu Procfile? Te funciona localmente con foreman o simplemente la estás ejecutando la aplicación con rails s?

Comment: También tengo este problema, lo resolvió?

Comment: hola, estoy ejecutando la aplicacion con rails s, no tengo Procfile ya que lo tenia para usar private_pub que usa faye y borre todos los cambios para empezar con cable, pense que podia ser eso pero volvi a hacer la parte con actioncable desde la branch master donde no tenia ningun cambio y se sigue rompiendo en heroku, al parecer algo que tengo configurado en produccion me esta rompiendo la app pero todavia no encontre que es.

Answer (score 0):

No entregas demasiada información, de hecho mi respuesta va solo basada en supuestos, ya que no muestras información de gemas, del deploy de la app, configuración de heroku o de tu aplicación que pueda dar alguna pista de la causa del problema. El primer problema que muestra tu log es:

```
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Al parecer estás seteando un puerto para la aplicación, siendo que Heroku lo asigna automáticamente. Revisa en el dashboard de heroku si tienes la variable `PORT` en *Config variables* o en tu código en general, quizás en `config/application.rb`, no lo se la verdad, como te digo esta respuesta va completamente a ciegas.
Tu otro problema es:

```
app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work' (see --tasks)
```

Con esto asumo que estás usando alguna gema para correr procesos en 2do plano como `delayed-job` o `resque`. Puede que el problema sea que no tienes un worker disponible para correr este proceso. Recuerda que la versión gratuita viene con uno disponible, el cual se usa en la aplicación web.

Ahora, creo que deberías agregar un `Procfile` a tu proyecto, donde especifiques cuales procesos correrá heroku y de que forma. Algo como:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

A la par con el Procfile, también agregar [`foreman`](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) a tu Gemfile para correr la aplicación localmente lo más similar posible a como se ejecutaría en Heroku.

Por último, si nada de esto funciona. Si dices que la aplicación funcionaba antes, has un `git revert` de los cambios hasta el commit que funcionaba y desde ahí ir viendo que cambios pudieron haber provocado el problema.